# Avoiding duplicates on concurrent reads off the same database table

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, concurrency

Avoiding duplicates on concurrent reads off the same database table

We have a table that contains a list of tasks

```
Table RecordsTable  
    RecordID
    RecordName
    ...
    ...
    IsProcessed
```

Multiple worker machines read off the table and once the task is processed mark IsProcessed as true.

So if we want the following code to work without duplicates

Pseudocode in C#

```
//get first 10 records that are not processed based on some other conditions
var recordSet = objectontext.recordstable.Where(...).Where(c => c.IsProcessed == false).Take(10);
//loop through the recordset in a transaction 
foreach(record singleRecord in recordSet)
{
    bool result = ProcessRecord();
    //Mark isProcessed as true 
    if(result)
        singleRecord.IsProcessed = true;
    objectContext.Savechanges();
}
```

We want to avoid duplicate processing of records (since the ProcessRecords() contain mailers and such). **If we wrap the entire code above in 
a transaction** does it mean that two calls from two different workers would result in non-duplicate records?

If workerA first issues the call to the table it gets,

```
var recordSetWorkerA = objectontext.recordstable.Where(somecondition...).Where(c => c.IsProcessed == false).Take(10);
```

If workerB issues a call after worker A already is in the transaction would the following statment fail to execute because trying to read locked rows
 or move to the next 10 records?

```
var recordSetWorkerB = objectontext.recordstable.Where(somecondition...).Where(c => c.IsProcessed == false).Take(10);
```

Is there any pattern we should be looking at.

Comment: In short: You will need stored procedure for retrieving tasks because this requires hand written SQL to make sure that only one worker will load those records and switch them to `Processing` state (as proposed in answers) in atomic operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrapping your code into transaction won't be enough. You'll of course get exception on `SaveChanges`, but it'll be too late.

What you really need is marking records as *being* processed, not just *completed* processing. I see two solutions:

1. If you workers share same state (meaning they are thread in one AppDomain, and not several concurrent worker services), you can use `ConcurrentDictionary` to mark records you're being processed.

   ```
   foreach(record singleRecord in recordSet)
   {
       //RecordsInProcess is a globally-available ConcurrentDictionary<recordIdType, record
       if (!RecordsInProcess.TryAdd(singleRecord.RecordId, singleRecord))
          continue; //TryAdd will return false if such an element already exists

       bool result = ProcessRecord();
       //Mark isProcessed as true 
       if(result)
           singleRecord.IsProcessed = true;
       objectContext.Savechanges();
       record junk; // we don't need it
       RecordsInProcess.TryRemove(singleRecordId, out junk)
   }
   ```
2. If you workers are isolated or you just want something more robust, then you have to mark records as processing in database and use that info for filtering. That's where you have to use transactions, and use them very carefully, because it's very easy to get deadlocked. Most efficient from concurrency point of view will be to always take only one unprocessed record from database, mark it as `processing` before you do anything and then continue with your processing.

Comment: Our workers are isolated. Different machines can come up and start processing the record at any given point of time. So we go with option 2 - Also the change we would need to make is not querying for top N matching records but retrieve and process records one by one. Would it make a difference if we got the top N records and within a transaction mark all of them as "Processing" and then continue with the processing - since in our case the processing might take a good bunch of time - we make a lot of calls to external web services etc.

Comment: No, it wouldn't, but you'll have to watch your transactions more closely.

Comment: You can use a single statement to get an task and mark it as yours.  An `UPDATE` with an `OUTPUT` clause can mark the task while returning the data needed to start processing.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to explicitly make isProcessed a tri-state enum of { ready, processing, processed }. I don't know how to do this in ActiveRecord, but you want a SQL statement like:

```
UPDATE RecordsTable
SET ProcessedState = 'processing'
WHERE RecordId = 1
    AND ProcessedState = 'ready';
```

Ensure that exactly one row was updated by this statement. If zero rows were, someone beat you to that task. Make sure that this statement executes in its own transaction with at least "read committed" isolation level.